# Geektool can't run imagemagick commands

Tags: macos, imagemagick, macports, automator, geektool

I recently installed imagemagick over macports to automatically crop images, but while the command works in terminal, it doesn't work in geektool. I tried using automator, but it doesn't work there either. Here's the code:

```
convert -crop 455x140+240+430 /Library/Desktop\ Pictures/Halo/Halo_Stats-full.png /Library/Desktop\ Pictures/Halo/Halo_Stats_Cropped.png
```

Any ideas why this isn't working? Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any kind of error message?  If so, what is it?

Comment: I didn't get any error message from the terminal because it worked fine there, and geektool doesn't display error messages, but automator gave me "-: convert command not found (127)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a path issue. If you type

```
which convert
```

At the terminal, I will give you the full path to convert. You should be able to use that whole string as the command instead of just "convert"